# Iterating through table rows text with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, rows

Trying to iterate each row to create list for all rows separately.
HTML table is;

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$90</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Ken</td>
    <td>March</td>
    <td>$70</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Dan</td>
    <td>April</td>
    <td>$60</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

And my python code is:

```
driver.get("file:///C:/HTML/new.html")
header = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/th")
row = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td")
head = len(header) # 3
r1 = len(row) # 5
headers = []
rows = []
for h in header:
    headers.append(h.text)
for r in row:
    rows.append(r.text)
print (headers)
print (rows)
```

Result:

```
['Name', 'Month', 'Savings']
['John', 'January', '$90']
```

Header part (["Name","Month","Savings"]) works as it should be but I couldn't build up for loop to create list for all rows separately. Tried few diff for loops but all turned up to be a nested for loop.. What I want to do is actually as follows to write excel file later on:

```
["Name","Month","Savings"]
['John','January','$90']
['Smith','February','$80']
['John','March','$70']
['John','January','$60']
```

I would be very happy if you guys could give advice. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply loop through the other trs and get all their td text you could do the following.

```
trs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table//tr")
for tr in trs[1:]:
    row=[td.text for td in tr.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")]
    print(row)
```

Comment: Didn't work out :( 
  row=[td.text for td in tr.find_elements_by_tag("td")]
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_tag'

Comment: It worked out perfectly :) love that, many thanks Arundeep. I think I should put the code of excel somewhere in for loop, right?

Comment: If you want to just add it to excel the print row would be replaced with a write to excel.

Comment: I spent weeks to handle this. Thanks a lot really

Comment: No problem was nothing much.